# Does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a^n}{\frac{n}{2}!}x^n$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, absolute-convergence

And if so, what is the radius of convergence of $x$?

I am inclined to think it converges absolutely for all $x$ but I can't prove it.

I have tried using an adaptation of the ratio test:

$\rho=\lim\frac{\frac{a^{n+2}}{\frac{n+2}{2}!}x^{n+2}}{\frac{a^n}{\frac{n}{2}!}x^n}=\lim\frac{a^{n+2}x^{n+2}}{\frac{n+2}{2}!}.\frac{\frac{n}{2}!}{a^nx^n}=\lim\frac{a^2x^2}{\frac{n+2}{2}}=\lim\frac{2a^2x^2}{n+2}$

and then this tends to $0$ and so, converges. But I'm sure that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you define $\frac{n}{2}!$ for odd $n$?

Comment: @DanielFischer That's partly why I am confused! I am not sure but I am assuming it means ignoring the cases where $n$ is odd... If so maybe it's better to set $m=\frac{n}{2}$ and go from there?

Comment: @DanielFischer If that is the case, can we write $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a^n}{\frac{n}{2}!}x^n$=$\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{a^{2m}}{m!}x^{2m}$. Otherwise we define $\frac{n}{2}!$ using the gamma function?

Comment: I would rather expect that $\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)$ is intended. That wouldn't change the fact that the series is absolutely convergent for all $x$, but of course the sum. Stirling's formula would show convergence, or you can consider the subseries with even and odd indices separately.

Comment: @DanielFischer So Stirling's formula is $n!>\sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n$. Then $\frac{n}{2}!>\sqrt{\pi n}(\frac{n}{2e})^{\frac{n}{2}}$. So then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a^n}{\frac{n}{2}!}x^n$<$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a^n}{\sqrt{n\pi}(\frac{n}{2e})^{\frac{n}{2}}}x^n$. Then we need to show that that converges?

Comment: Roughly. Yes, estimate the term by $$\left(\frac{\sqrt{2e}ax}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n$$ for example.

Comment: @DanielFischer If we consider the even and odd terms separately, does the sum of the even terms converge to $e^{x^2}$? And for the odd terms, do I use Stirling's formula to show that the sum converges or did you mean there is a different method if you split the even and odd terms?

Comment: @DanielFischer I have a strong impression it can be proven easily even if we use $n-1$ instead of odd $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The series converges absolutely for any real (or complex) $x$. One way to see this is to separate the series into even and odd terms. The even terms give $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (ax)^{2k}/k!$, which converges absolutely for any $x$ by the ratio test. The ratio test will also work for the odd terms, no matter what reasonable definition of $\frac{2k+1}2!$ you use. And the sum of two absolutely convergent series is again absolutely convergent, no matter what order you combine the terms in.

Comment: Won't the even terms give $\sum_{2k=0}^\infty\frac{a^{2k}}{k!}x^{2k}$ though? Can you change $2k$ to $k$ with no effect?

Comment: Ignore my last comment. I answered it myself.